# Remove Extra Space in Collection View in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

[image: Desired Output like this image]

**Code:**

```
let reuseIdentifier = "cell" 
var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4","5","6","7","8", "9", "10", "11","12","13","14"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: CGFloat((collectionView.frame.size.width / 2) - 8), height: CGFloat(250))
}
```

Comment: image is not visible

Comment: can you paste screenshot?

Comment: You should explain the issue you're having and show what you've tried to fix it. Is the extra space on the horizontal axis? vertical axis? between cells? between sections? Please elaborate so you can help us help you.

Comment: @ShyamShukla :  upload your screenshot on some image uploading site like http://imgur.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: my screenshot link here.https://ibb.co/jeXYov

Comment: I am having this exact issue, did you manage to fix it? It happens when the collection cells heights are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Do this according to your requirements hope it will help you to get an idea.

```
  let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 1, bottom: 5, right: 0) // according to your requirements
            layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1 // according to your requirements
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1// according to your requirements
```

If you want more help or this not work for you, you can also go through that [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest) which can help you to achieve your goal. Click on this [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)

Answer (score 0):

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
 {
return CGSize(width: CGFloat((collectionView.frame.size.width / 2) - 8), height: (collectionView.frame.size. height / 3) - 8))
}
```